# How to know if an elb is handling a high load?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-elb

We are experiencing a high traffic load, and the great mayority of requests are failing. We have added more instances behind our elb but that does not solve the issue. Our db is at 50% cpu usage. Is there a way to test if the elb is the one that cannot handle the load?

Answer (score 0):

ELB scales infinitely so it's almost never became bottleneck. You can start from CloudWatch metrics, but it's will be good to check VPC flow logs, not only http response codes from ELB.

Also, ALB have log feature that need to be turned on manually